How do I animate two intersecting shapes and make the intersection be transparent or see through in After Effects, is there an easy way?
So, in After Effects, I have two animated objects, and when they intersect, I want the image below to be see-through. I can't seem to find a solution, but there is surely a way to make their intersections transparent no?

If the two black blocks in your example are Shape objects (ie vector shapes drawn in After Effects), you can put them both in a single Shape layer, then add a "Merge Paths" to them, and choose "Exclude Intersections" for the mode:

If they are video or other types of bitmapped objects, you could do it with track mattes.
Put the two images/videos on two different layers, and enable Track Mattes on both. Set one matte to target the other layer and vice versa. You will need to click on the eyeball icon to re-enable visibility of the mattes after you create them, as the matted layer gets made invisible by default:


Thanks so much! That's exactly what I was looking for!
